# I want to change to "Get the height of a specific element"

Tags: javascript, html

I use [scrollama.js](https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/scrollama/blob/master/build/scrollama.js).
scrollama is a plugin that allows to center reference lines using Intersection Observer.

---

### What I want to do

[image: like this]

Now (default), I get the center based on `body`,
I want to get the center based on the specific element `.main`.

---

### Code likely to be relevant

Line 213

```
function handleResize() {
    // from here
    viewH = window.innerHeight;
    pageH = getPageHeight();

    offsetMargin = offsetVal * viewH;
    // to here

    if (isReady) {
      stepOffsetHeight = stepEl.map(function (el) { return el.offsetHeight; });
      stepOffsetTop = stepEl.map(getOffsetTop);
      if (isEnabled) { updateIO(); }
    }

    if (isDebug) { update({ id: id, stepOffsetHeight: stepOffsetHeight, offsetMargin: offsetMargin, offsetVal: offsetVal }); }
  }
```

I want to get the specific element `.main`, how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

.Dear Pop,

```
var main_height = document.getElementById('.main').offsetHeight;
var main_height_withpadding = document.getElementById('.main').clientHeight;

var main_height_mid = main_height/2;
```

Comment: Thank you. Since viewH and pageH are used several times in the plug-in, I would like to put in the place of viewH and pageH if possible. (I want to change "only where to get elements")

By the way, I replaced it with `viewH = document.querySelector("main").offsetHeight;` and `pageH = document.querySelector("main").offsetHeight;`.
But the error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'offsetHeight' of null`. It didn't go well.
Is there anything missing? Where I'm going wrong?